# VC++ how to ignore \" in a String

Tags: c++

```
String^ fileName = "C:\Users\source\repos\Project1\" + textBox1->Text + ".txt";
```

How to ignore the \" ?
[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrXd3.png)

Comment: This is not `C` code.  This is not `C++` code.  It looks like `C++/CX` code, which is not C nor C++.

Comment: You can also use `/` as a path separator on Windows and avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. You need to escape the '\'.

```
String^ fileName = "C:\\Users\\source\\repos\\Project1\\" + textBox1->Text + ".txt";
```

Comment: Please flag/vote to close obvious duplicates instead of answering.